# Get Data from Workbook opened from an email

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I get Excel workbooks emailed to me. These are the same format and data etc. but the name of the file alters by the current time date stamp.

I use a VBA SQL query to grab data.
It works if I save the Excel workbook to the hard drive.
It doesn't work if I haven't saved the workbook even if it is open on the desktop.

The problem seems to be the path. If when the email comes in I double click on the workbook and save it then as expected the path is of the normal form i.e.
*C:\TEST\SQL_DataGrabFrom_Excel*.

If I just double click on the workbook it will open and I can see the data but the the path is reported to be
*C\Users\Auser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.Outlook\3G79AVIT*.

VBA doesn't recognise this as a valid path/file.

Comment: Please show the code that is giving you problems and quote any error messages

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write a simple version and this lead me to the answer.

If I open the workbook by double clicking the file in an email and then do a list of all open workbooks it gives me the odd path to the workbook

"C:\Users\AUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.Outlook\3G81AVIT"

Using this path fails but using the non fully qualified path containing just the workbook name works.

```
Sub GetDatainSource()
    Dim SF As String
    Dim TF As String
    SF = "MySourceFile.xlsx"
    TF = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(SF).Worksheets("Title").Range("A1").Copy _
      Workbooks(TF).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub
```